# Issue with waiting for an Event in curio

Tags: python, python-asyncio, curio

I'm using `curio` to implement a mechanism of two tasks that communicate using a `curio.Event` object. The first task (called `action()`) runs first, and `awaits` the event to be set. The second task (called `setter()`) runs after the first one, and is setting the event.

The code is the following:

```
import curio

evt = curio.Event()


async def action():
    await evt.wait()
    print('Performing action')


async def setter():
    await evt.set()
    print('Event set')


async def run():
    task = await curio.spawn(action())
    await setter()
    print('Finished run')
    await task.wait()


curio.run(run())
```

The output is the following:

```
Event set
Finished run
Performing action
```

Which means that `print('Performing action')` is executed AFTER `print('Finished run')`, and that's what I'm trying to prevent - I was expecting that calling `await evt.set()` will also invoke all of its waiters, and `run()` won't continue until all of the waiters were invoked, meaning that `action()` will be continued BEFORE `print('Finished run')` is executed. This is the output I would like to have:

```
Event set
Performing action
Finished run
```

What am I getting wrong? Is there any way to change this behavior? I would like to have more control over the execution order.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting `Event` is a way to signal that something happened: it as you already noted doesn't provide invocation of waiters.

If you want to report run finished after action performed you should report it after awaiting for action:

```
async def run():
    task = await curio.spawn(action())
    await setter()
    await task.wait()  # await action been performed
    print('Finished run')  # and only after that reporting run() is done
```

---

If you want to block execution of `run()` until something happened you can do it with another event `wait()` that should be `set()` when this something happend:

```
import curio

evt = curio.Event()
evt2 = curio.Event()


async def action():
    await evt.wait()
    print('Performing action')
    await evt2.set()
    print('Event 2 set')


async def setter():
    await evt.set()
    print('Event set')


async def run():
    task = await curio.spawn(action())
    await setter()    
    await evt2.wait()
    print('Finished run')
    await task.wait()


curio.run(run())
```

Res:

```
Event set
Performing action
Event 2 set
Finished run
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I now understand better. I guess that my use case is pretty common, which makes me think - is there any existing mechanism that fits to my use cases better than curio.Event? Just to clarify - the mechanism should allow one side to wait for an event (multiple waiters can exist), and another side setting the event *and* waiting for all of its waiters to finish processing, and then continues.

Comment: @imriqwe I'm afraid I'm out of idea here. I can't say I ever saw existing solution for `asyncio`.